# Does $\exp(-x) \sin(x)$ have infinite oscillations AND an infinite number of real roots?

Tags: limits, analysis, roots

*A Course of Pure Mathematics* by G. H. Hardy states that a function oscillates if it does NOT tend to a limit or to $± \infty$. I find this definition difficult to square with $e^{-x}\sin(x)$. It has limit $0$ as $x$ tends to positive infinity and also an infinite number of roots, located at integer multiples of $π$ and as such it must have an infinite number of turning points and by extension must oscillate between positive and negative values indefinitely. I welcome comments which clarify this apparent 'contradiction'.

Comment: If Hardy provides a definition/motivation of "oscillate" elsewhere, you should write it here. If his definition of "oscillate" is as given in the first sentence of your post, then I guess we can't say much beyond the fact that it does not agree with your definition of oscillate. Perhaps his notion of oscillate requires the "amplitude" to be non-vanishing.

Comment: Does the oscillation of a function require periodicity as well?

Comment: Hardy : a function oscillates if it does NOT have a limit or tend to ± infinity.  Chapter 4, paragraph 62. He gives examples and they are consistent with his definition (which I have so far failed to find in other sources).

Comment: What you have stated in your comment is the inverse of the logical proposition in your post body not the contrapositive, which means they are not logically equivalent.

Comment: Kermani: periodicity is not mentioned in the definition by Hardy.

Comment: @QuadraticReciprocity $\;e^{-x} \sin x\,$ does *not* "oscillate" according to Hardy's definition. Whether Hardy's definition is consistent with definitions elsewhere, or with your intuition of what an "oscillating function" is supposed to be, that is an entirely different matter.

Comment: Munshi: you are right, my error, now corrected so thank you.

Comment: @dxiv: That's a good point and I agree but it is difficult to accept that $e^{-x}sin(x)$ does not oscillate. I am aware other definitions of oscillate exist and they must (should) be consistent with Hardy's definition.

Comment: The function you have does oscillate. The logical implication from Hardy is that if it does neither, it definitely does oscillate. In other words these are sufficient, but not necessary conditions to conclude oscillatory behavior.

Comment: @dxiv This should be an official answer.

Comment: @PaulFrost Done, with some additional notes.

Comment: @NinadMunshi This is a definition (quoted in full in my answer), not just any statement, and "*we say that...*" means "*if and only if*" in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Hardy's definition copied from Project Gutenberg's [A Course of Pure Mathematics](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/38769).

> **62. Oscillating Functions.** $\text{Definition.}$ When $ϕ(n)$ does not tend to a limit, nor to $+ ∞$, nor to $−∞$, as $n$ tends to $∞$, we say that $ϕ(n)$ **oscillates** as $n$ tends to $∞$.

According to this definition, the function $\,f(x)=e^{-x} \sin(x)\,$ does *not*
oscillate when $\,x \to \infty\,$, since the  limit at $\,+\infty\,$ exists, and is in fact $\,0\,$.

A related concept is that of [oscillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillation_(mathematics)) of a function, and the oscillation of this $\,f(x)\,$ at $\,+\infty\,$ is $\,0\,$. Hardy's definition is equivalent to saying that a function *oscillates* at $\,+\infty\,$ iff  the *oscillation* at $\,+\infty\,$ is finite and strictly greater than zero.

It is true that $\,f(x)\,$ changes sign infinitely many times, and does so in every neighborhood of $\,+\infty\,$, but it "flatlines" and has the horizontal axis as an asymptote. Such functions are sometimes caled [damped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping) oscillations, though it would be less common to call them "oscillating functions" generically (nor does the OP quote any specific source that uses an alternative definition under which $\,f(x)\,$ would be called an "oscillating function").

Comment: Thank you and I agree. I also found the concept of the oscillation of a function (Wikipedia). I like the point about the asymptotic 'flat lining' of $f(x)$ and I am coming around the idea that there is an essential difference in the oscillatory behaviour of $f(x)$ and $sin(x)$ as $x$ tends to infinity. Thanks to all who contributed.